# Initialize data from database once and iterate through items with switch/case

Tags: java, spring

I have a method which converts input String to another String (search in database):

```
public String convert(String input) {
   Optional<Item> itemBy = itemRepository.findBySourceValue(input);
   if (itemBy.isPresent()) {
       return itemBy.get().getConvertedValue();
   }
   log.error("Invalid item {}", itemBy);
   return itemBy;
}
```

Item entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "items_conversions", schema = "items")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Item {

    private String sourceValue;

    private String convertedValue;

}
```

The problem is... I use this method in Stream and convert many items (about 5,000), so it will perform 5000 connections to database or even more.

Typical Item object contains 2 Strings like:

```
sourceValue: "ws_id"
convertedValue: "res:id"
```

**First:** I need to initialize and get all values from database once. I guess solution with `@PostConstruct` is okay:

```
 private List<Item> items;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        items = itemsRepository.findAll();
    }
```

But maybe I have a better option?

And **second:**

So i need to write some switch/case method to convert values:

```
switch (input) {
    case "ws_id":
        return "res:id";
    case "ws_amount":
        return "res:all";
    ...
    default:
        return input;
}
```

But not with hardcode Strings -> with values from `Item` object from database. Like this:

```
 switch (input) {
    case items.get(index).getSourceValue:
        return items.get(index).getConvertedValue;
...
//and this for all values in list
}
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Put the data into a `Map`:

```
private Map<String, String> itemMap;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    itemMap = itemsRepository.findAll().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Item::getSourceValue, Item::getConvertedValue));
}


public String convert(String input) {
   String value = itemMap.get(input);
   if (value == null) {
      log.error("Invalid input {}", input );
      return "";
   }
   return value;
}
```

BTW, your original `convert` doesn't make much sense. It tries to return an (always empty) `Optional` as a `String`.